Corrupted State Error on pallet-staking
We're getting these error during cargo test for pallet-staking, pallet-offences & pallet-nomination-pools after it is implemented locally in our node template without any modifications to the code. What would be the issue possibly (implementation mistakes) would be helpful and any ideas on how to solve this error?
Command :
cargo test --features runtime-benchmarks

Error :
ERROR runtime::storage: Corrupted state at `[95, 62, 73, 7, 247, 22, 172, 137, 182, 52, 125, 21, 236, 236, 237, 202, 66, 42, 219, 87, 159, 29, 191, 79, 56, 134, 197, 207, 163, 187, 140, 196, 142, 121, 253, 241, 66, 142, 149, 132, 46, 170, 154, 240, 178, 36, 20, 190, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]: Error { cause: Some(Error { cause: None, desc: "BoundedVec exceeds its limit" }), desc: "Could not decode `StakingLedger::claimed_rewards`" }

ERROR runtime::storage: Corrupted state at `[95, 62, 73, 7, 247, 22, 172, 137, 182, 52, 125, 21, 236, 236, 237, 202, 66, 42, 219, 87, 159, 29, 191, 79, 56, 134, 197, 207, 163, 187, 140, 196, 142, 121, 253, 241, 66, 142, 149, 132, 46, 170, 154, 240, 178, 36, 20, 190, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]: Error { cause: Some(Error { cause: None, desc: "BoundedVec exceeds its limit" }), desc: "Could not decode `StakingLedger::unlocking`" }` 

ERROR frame_support::storage: (key, value) failed to decode at [95, 62, 73, 7, 247, 22, 172, 137, 182, 52, 125, 21, 236, 236, 237, 202, 156, 106, 99, 127, 98, 174, 42, 241, 199, 227, 30, 237, 126, 150, 190, 4, 235, 95, 111, 74, 228, 239, 173, 201, 61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]: Error { cause: Some(Error { cause: None, desc: "BoundedVec exceeds its limit" }), desc: "Could not decode `Nominations::targets`" } 

ERROR runtime::storage: Corrupted state at `[95, 62, 73, 7, 247, 22, 172, 137, 182, 52, 125, 21, 236, 236, 237, 202, 156, 106, 99, 127, 98, 174, 42, 241, 199, 227, 30, 237, 126, 150, 190, 4, 76, 25, 92, 185, 119, 49, 206, 125, 101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]: Error { cause: Some(Error { cause: None, desc: "BoundedVec exceeds its limit" }), desc: "Could not decode `Nominations::targets`" }`

ERROR runtime: a defensive failure has been triggered; please report the block number at https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues: DefensiveError::PoolNotFound 

Points to consider :

The node is building successfully and all of the tests are passing, while we get these errors on corrupted state, storage errors, and the defensive error.
The runtime/Cargo.toml

